# PostGIS ERROR: function x(geometry) does not exist

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I am using the following postgis query for updating a pgrouting table from my custom road data. In the `x(ST_StartPoint(part_geom)) as x1,` line its returning an error mentioned

> ERROR:  function x(geometry) does not exist

```
INSERT INTO public.roads_r (
SELECT DISTINCT ON (the_geom)
nextval('public.roads_r_gid_seq') AS gid,
gid AS parent_gid,
name,
no,
type,
NULL as source,
NULL as target,
ST_Length(part_geom, true) as cost,
ST_Length(part_geom, true) as reverse_cost,
x(ST_StartPoint(part_geom)) as x1,
y(ST_StartPoint(part_geom)) as y1,
x(ST_EndPoint(part_geom)) as x2,
y(ST_EndPoint(part_geom)) as y2,
NULL as to_cost,
NULL as rule,
ST_Multi(part_geom) AS the_geom
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.gid, 
        a.geom, 
        (ST_Dump(ST_Union(b.geom))).geom AS part_geom, 
        a.road_name as name,
        a.road_no as no,
        a.road_type as type
    FROM public.roads as a, public.roads as b
    WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
    GROUP BY a.gid, a.geom, a.road_name, a.road_no, a.road_type
) AS res
WHERE ST_Contains(geom, part_geom) = true OR ST_Contains(ST_Buffer(geom, 0.00001), part_geom) = true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No function exists in PostGIS called "x", as the error is telling you.

I am guessing you want to be using the [`ST_X()`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_X.html) and  [`ST_Y()`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Y.html) functions, instead.

Comment: I got another problem in the same code. Now its indication "ST_Multi(part_geom) AS the_geom" and returning an error "INSERT has more expressions than target columns". Could you please give me a kind suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I think ST_X(geom) is what you are looking for.

where did you find that x(geom) syntax?

Comment: I got another problem in the same code. Now its indication "ST_Multi(part_geom) AS the_geom" and returning an error "INSERT has more expressions than target columns". Could you please give me a kind suggestion?